# If I have no creatures, can my opponent attack me with multiple creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Also, if I only have one creature, can my opponent attack me with multiple creatures at the same time?

Comment: It would be dumb if having no creatures was a better defence than having creatures.

Comment: Hmm not to be a pain but you should really relearn the basics of combat in magic the gathering.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

There are only three restrictions in the rules limiting the choice of which creatures can be declared as attackers<sup>[CR 508.1a]</sup>:

1. They must be creatures your control.
2. They must be untapped.
3. They must have Haste if they havn't been under your control since the beginning of your turn.

The number of creatures controlled by the defender is not a factor.

Note that certain cards have abilities that impose additional restrictions. For example, [Master of Cruelties](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Master%20of%20Cruelties).

Answer (score 0):

There are cards which restrict the number of creatures that can attack in a turn, but unless one of them is active, there are no limitations on how many creatures can be declared as attackers.